# Azure DevOps - release pipeline - Impossible to switch back from Deny to Allow permissions for 'Administer release permissions'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, user-permissions

In the security of the release pipeline, I have changed the permissions of 'Administer release permissions' to Deny for the Test Team from the release pipeline window (below the different screens to arrive to the permissions to change).

Step 1
[image]

Step 2
[image]

But I've been stuck for a few hours trying switching back the permissions from Deny to Allow to the 'Administer release permissions'.

I can't switch back to Allow permissions because all permissions are disabled now.
Is-it possible switch back to Allow permission?
If it is, i will be enjoy if you can explain me how?

Thanks in advance.